# Notify answerers when bounty is awarded, even if to someone else

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications

You've answered a question that has an open bounty. You hope the bounty will be awarded to your hard-worked-on answer. But there are other answers, and some of them are good as well.

If you are awarded the bounty you will of course receive a notification. But if you are not, there's no way for you to know which answer got the bounty. Even checking the "featured" question list won't work: when the bounty is awarded, the question disappears from that list.

So, I think it would be a good idea to notify all answerers of a bounty question when the bounty has been awarded. Most of those answerers probably want to know which answer finally got the bounty.

Comment: I don't think a lot of users would want a notification for "you *didn't* receive the bounty"... If you're one that cares to see where it ended up, keep tabs on it, bookmark it, whatever. Go look yourself when it's ended.

Comment: @animuson Put it another way: many users want to know _why they didn't get the bounty_. That is, know who won, see how many votes that other answer finally got, etc

Comment: I don't think many users would care that much, and imagine a lot of users would look at the notification and go "meh, whatever" and dismiss it (me being one of them).

Comment: I see your point. But that would apply to many other notifications, and yet those notifications exist because some users do care.

Answer (score 3):

This would be more likely to create unnecessary negative drama than it would promote any constructive understanding. Because the bounty award is at the discretion of the offerer, there really isn't much point in re-visiting questions that have closed bounties. For those folks that didn't get it, it would either be a useless annoyance (maybe they didn't answer for the bounty in the first place!) or it would be an active disappointment that may or may not have a discernible reason

Best to just let it go. This isn't the evening news, we don't need to highlight every "juicy" bit of bad news we can get our hands on.

Comment: "_Maybe they didn't answer for the bounty in the first place_": In that case they __wouldn't__ be notified, according to my proposal. "_We don't need to highlight every juicy bit of bad news_": As I said, my point is not to give bad news. The bad news has __already__ been given, right? You didn't get the bounty!